# LinkedIn API Statistics Finder Demographics

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to fetch campaign report by demographics.

Its **available in the UI** but can't found it in the API.

Statistics Finder uses two pivots, but there is **no option** to do:

```
pivots[0] = CAMPAIGN 

pivots[1] = MEMBER_COMPANY_SIZE / MEMBER_INDUSTRY / MEMBER_SENIORITY / MEMBER_JOB_TITLE / MEMBER_JOB_FUNCTION / MEMBER_COUNTRY / MEMBER_REGION / MEMBER_COMPANY
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#statistics-finder

Using Analytics Finder and request per campaign per demographic - **is unworthy**.

Is there other option that I'm missing?